# Declare a Room variable that's @Nullable in memory but @NonNull in the SQLite database?

Tags: android-studio, android-room

Here's the canonical example:

```
@Entity
class Kozmique {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull  // TODO  how to be non-null in the database but nullable in memory?
    public Long id;
```

In memory, nobody should assign `kozmique.id` except one oracle - the return value of `KozmiqueDao.insert`. So to create a `Kozmique` and enter it in the database one must run temporarily with a null `id`.

But in the database, the ID should be `NOT NULL` because the instant a NULL slips in we want an error message.

So how do I tell Room exactly what I need, instead of allowing Room to exploit a hybrid of SQL and Java which is inexact with both?

---

The fallback position is this:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
long id = 0;
```

Now the SQLite database correctly contains `NOT NULL`...

...but Android-Studio has a snit-fit and warns me "don't put a @NonNull on a primitive type".

And in this mode I NEED a primitive type, in the Java, because I WANT a syntax error if anything assigns or compares `null`.

All this fun could be avoided if Room did not borrow `@NotNull`, which means something else, as the flag for `NOT NULL` in the SQL. `@ColumnInfo` should support a `NOT_NULL` flag.

Comment: Given you've annotated the PK with autoGenerate, and Room expects a value of `0` to mean "no key assigned", and I believe Room also requires public getters & setters (which must set & return 0 as expected by Room), I think you're not able to change the id field on the db model. So that seems to suggest you have only 1 choice; to wrap the db model with a business layer model that exposes the id as `Long?`, remapping 0 to null.

Comment: Have you try just using the primitive type: `public long id = 0;` ? When the value is `0` Room will still auto-generate the id.

Comment: My example is just an example. I think Room should support a "NOT NULL" directive without the exact semantics of @NonNull

Comment: Wouldn't that be dangerous? You would need to protect yourself and fellow developers from not accidentally inserting a null value to a NOT NULL column, which is exactly what `@NonNull` is doing here, giving you that compile-time safety.

Maybe make the field package-protected or private and have a constructor that Room can use? That way there is no direct field setter.